# Is there a way to maintain the length of a user entered number, to prevent removal of extra 0's?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a Diabetes management algorithm, and I'm trying to find a way for the user's entered time blocks to be maintained at 4 digits

I've been searching on google, but all I have been able to find is how to check the length of a variable, which I already know how to do.

```
 Sub timeBlocks()
        Dim file As String = "C:\Users\Connor\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\meterCodeMaybe\TIMEBLOCKS.txt"
        Dim blockNum As Integer
        Console.WriteLine("Please be sure to enter times as a 24 hour value, rather than 12 hour, otherwise the input will not be handled.")
        Console.Write("Please enter the amount of time blocks you require for your day: ")
        blockNum = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim timeA(blockNum - 1) As Integer
        Dim timeB(blockNum - 1) As Integer
        Dim sensitivity(blockNum - 1) As Integer
        Dim ratio(blockNum - 1) As Integer
        For i = 0 To (blockNum - 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the start time of your time block")
            timeA(i) = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the end time of your time block")
            timeB(i) = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the ratio for this time block (Enter the amount of carbs that go into 1 unit of insulin)")
            ratio(i) = Console.ReadLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the insulin sensitivity for this time block 
(amount of blood glucose (mmol/L) that is reduced by 1 unit of insulin.)")
            sensitivity(i) = Console.ReadLine()
            FileOpen(1, file, OpenMode.Append)
            PrintLine(1, Convert.ToString(timeA(i)) + "-" + Convert.ToString(timeB(i)) + " 1:" + Convert.ToString(ratio(i)) + " Insulin Sensitivity:" + Convert.ToString(sensitivity(i)) + " per mmol/L")

            FileClose(1)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Basically, I want the user to be able to enter a 4 digit number for their time block, to match a 24 hr time, so if they enter 0000, it is displayed as this, however, it removes all previous 0's and sets it to just 0.

Comment: A possible issue, `blockNum = Console.ReadLine()`, what if you type something other than a number? Also IMHO look into [List(Of T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Can you hold the value as a string rather than an integer?

Comment: That's not a number, it's a *code*. Like a phone *number* (not a number). You need a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps pad the number with 4 leading 0's:

```
Right(String(digits, "0") & timeA(i), 4)
```

Or as an alternative, store the value as a string so that it can be printed out in its original form.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Function to get a 24 hours format time from user, I hope it would help:

```
  Public Function Read24HFormatTime() As String
        Dim str As String = String.Empty
        While True
            Dim c As Char = Console.ReadKey(True).KeyChar
            If c = vbCr Then Exit While
            If c = vbBack Then
                If str <> "" Then
                    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1)
                    Console.Write(vbBack & " " & vbBack)
                End If
            ElseIf str.Length < 5 Then
                If Char.IsDigit(c) OrElse c = ":" Then
                    If str.Length = 0 Then
                        ' allow 0, 1 or 2 only 
                        If c = "0" OrElse c = "1" OrElse c = "2" Then
                            Console.Write(c)
                            str += c
                        End If
                    ElseIf str.Length = 1 Then
                        If str = "0" Then
                            'allow 1 to 9
                            If c <> ":" Then
                                If CInt(c.ToString) >= 1 AndAlso CInt(c.ToString) <= 9 Then
                                    Console.Write(c)
                                    str += c
                                End If
                            End If
                        ElseIf str = "1" Then
                            'allow  0 to 9
                            If c <> ":" Then
                                If CInt(c.ToString) >= 0 AndAlso CInt(c.ToString) <= 9 Then
                                    Console.Write(c)
                                    str += c
                                End If
                            End If
                        ElseIf str = "2" Then
                            'allow  0 to 4
                            If c <> ":" Then
                                If CInt(c.ToString) >= 0 AndAlso CInt(c.ToString) <= 4 Then
                                    Console.Write(c)
                                    str += c
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    ElseIf str.Length = 2 Then
                        'allow  ":" only
                        If c = ":" Then
                            Console.Write(c)
                            str += c
                        End If
                    ElseIf str.Length = 3 Then
                        If str = "24:" Then
                            'allow  0 only
                            If c = "0" Then
                                Console.Write(c)
                                str += c
                            End If
                        Else
                            'allow  0 to 5
                            If c <> ":" Then
                                If CInt(c.ToString) >= 0 AndAlso CInt(c.ToString) <= 5 Then
                                    Console.Write(c)
                                    str += c
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    ElseIf str.Length = 4 Then
                        If str.Substring(0, 3) = "24:" Then
                            'allow  0 only
                            If c = "0" Then
                                Console.Write(c)
                                str += c
                            End If
                        Else
                            'allow  0 to 9
                            If c <> ":" Then
                                If CInt(c.ToString) >= 0 AndAlso CInt(c.ToString) <= 9 Then
                                    Console.Write(c)
                                    str += c
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End While
        Return str
    End Function
```

The user can only enter time like `23:59` `08:15` `13:10` and he couldn't enter formats like `35:10` `90:00` `25:13` `10:61`

This is a sample code to show you how to use it:

```
 Dim myTime = DateTime.Parse(Read24HFormatTime())
 Dim name = "Emplyee"
 Console.WriteLine($"{vbCrLf}Hello, {name}, at {myTime:t}")
 Console.ReadKey(True)
```